# Error when trying to do math equation

Tags: c#, math, sum

I am new to Console Application, I usually use C# for Unity. The code doesn't really work how I want it

Yes I know using Goto isn't good. But I don't know alternatives

I had [ a = 2 ] [ b = 3 ] and [ ans = a+b ] so the obvious answer is 5. So when you put 5 it runs the Else statement which is getting it incorrect.

```
        goto start;
        error:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Input not Recognized");
        Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
        Console.WriteLine("\nType (Reset) to Reset Program");
        Console.WriteLine("\nType (End) to End Program");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string error1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (error1.Equals("reset", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            goto start;
        }
        if (error1.Equals("end", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            goto error;
        }
        start:
        Console.WriteLine("Solve the Math Equation");
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int ans = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine("\n2 + 3");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string user = "";
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;

        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                double val = 0;
                bool _x = double.TryParse(key.KeyChar.ToString(), out val);
                if (_x)
                {
                    user += key.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && user.Length > 0)
                {
                    user = user.Substring(0, (user.Length - 1));
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                }
            }
        }
        while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        if (user.Equals(ans)) 
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            Console.WriteLine("\nYour answer " + ans);
            Console.WriteLine("\nType (End) to End Program");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            string end1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (end1.Equals("end", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                goto error;
            }
        }
         else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect!");
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe answer was " + ans);
                Console.WriteLine("\nType (Reset) to Reset Program");
                Console.WriteLine("Type (End) to End Program");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                string rne1 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (rne1.Equals("reset", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                Console.Clear();
                    goto start;
                }
                if (rne1.Equals("end", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                    goto error;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user` and `ans` are not equal in your code which is why your code jumps to the error. The reason why they are not equal are their Types.

`user` is a string
`ans` is an integer

So you are comparing "5" to 5 and that can not be equal.

Convert one of the variables so you have the same type.

Either use `user.Equals(ans.ToString())` in the if statement or convert the string to a number (which is the better solution IMO - because it also handles the situation when the input is not a number). Like this:

```
int userAns;
if (!Int32.TryParse(user, userAnsj))
   Console.WriteLine("Input is not a valid integer.");
```

and then comapare `userAns` to `ans`.